# implement DialogFragments to alert dialog that run from a BroadcastReceiver

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver, android-alertdialog, android-dialogfragment

I am trying to understand how to use the dialog fragment to run an alert dialog from a broadcast receiver , which simulate the toast massage.

however the below alert dialog is running well but it interrupting the user every time the alert dialog call from the broadcast receiver by stopping video playback and dismiss the keyboard ....etc

I tried to use the fragment and to call the show() method from the broadcast receiver but I end up with nothing.

The bellow is the alert dialog activity I use:

```
public class Alertactivity  extends Activity {

    @SuppressWarnings("ResourceType")
    @Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    setTheme(R.style.Theme_Transparent);
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        String mynames[] = { };

        int rando = (int) (Math.random() * xx);

        AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);

        final AlertDialog alertDialog = builder.create();

                alertDialog.getWindow().setLayout(600, 400);

        LayoutInflater inflater = alertDialog.getLayoutInflater();

        int k = (int) (Math.random() * 5);

        final View dialoglayout = inflater.inflate(new int[]{R.layout.mycustom_toast, R.layout.mycustom_toastx, R.layout.mycustom_toastx1, R.layout.mycustom_toastx2, R.layout.mycustom_toastx3}[k], null);

        Object localObject2;

        localObject2 = (TextView) ((View) dialoglayout).findViewById(R.id.toastText);
        ((TextView) localObject2).setText(mynames[rando]);

        (alertDialog).setView((View) dialoglayout);
        alertDialog.getWindow().setBackgroundDrawable(new ColorDrawable(android.graphics.Color.TRANSPARENT));


        WindowManager.LayoutParams wlp = alertDialog.getWindow().getAttributes();


    Window window = alertDialog.getWindow();


        int j = (int) (Math.random() * 8);
        wlp.gravity = new int[]{Gravity.CENTER, Gravity.LEFT, Gravity.RIGHT, Gravity.BOTTOM, Gravity.TOP, Gravity.TOP, Gravity.CENTER_HORIZONTAL, Gravity.CENTER_VERTICAL}[j];

        wlp.dimAmount = 0.0f;
        alertDialog.show();
    this.setFinishOnTouchOutside(true);

                   dialoglayout.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Alertactivity.this.finish();
            }
        });

        alertDialog.setOnDismissListener(new OnDismissListener() {

            @Override
            public void onDismiss(DialogInterface dialoglayout) {

                Alertactivity.this.finish();

            }
        });


        Timer mTimer = new Timer();
        mTimer.schedule(new TimerTask() {

            public void run() {

                Alertactivity.this.finish();
            }
        }, 10000);


   }

}
```

And the activity is called from a broadcast receiver every set of time:

```
 Intent startIntent = new Intent(paramContext, Alertactivity.class);
            startIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
            paramContext.startActivity(startIntent);
```

What I need to do is to implement this alert to an alert dialog fragment, in order to avoid interrupting the user and stooping any video playback or dismiss the keyboard "if the user is typing" and so on

Comment: I don't know if you could find that, but if i were developing the app, i would have a popped a notification, instead of a dialog. So on clicking the notification you can open your dialog if you want.

Comment: as i know the toast notification is not clickable!

Comment: is there is a way to have a clickable toast ?

Comment: Don't create a toast, as i said create a notification. If you want some kind of clickable toast, use SnackBar. https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/design/widget/Snackbar.html